# Autoresolve DataFactory IR in Managed Virtual Network status FAILED

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

After redeployment of Data Factory we encounter a FAILED status on the AutoResolve IR - Managed Virtual Network. The ADF is also connected to Azure DevOps Git so we have the JSON ARM Templates and the versions of adf_publish branch.
Some suggestion on how to debug this issue as this is the default IR?

[image]

```
{
    "name": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
    "properties": {
        "type": "Managed",
        "typeProperties": {
            "computeProperties": {
                "location": "AutoResolve",
                "dataFlowProperties": {
                    "computeType": "General",
                    "coreCount": 8,
                    "timeToLive": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "managedVirtualNetwork": {
            "type": "ManagedVirtualNetworkReference",
            "referenceName": "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by redeployment of ARM Templates.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change "location": "AutoResolve" to the same location as the DataFactory is being deployed to, I.E.:

"location": "eastus".